# What size heat shrink tubing do I need to repair this wire?

Tags: electrical, repair, range

What size heat shrink tubing do I need to repair this wire on an electric range?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selected heat shrink diameter will be based on the ratio of the shrink tubing, likely to be two to one for the less expensive stuff and three to one for the slightly higher priced tubing.

Your wire in the photo would easily take 1/8" heat shrink tubing with a two to one shrink ratio.

Consider also using a product called solder sleeves, available on eBay and other locations. If you are joining bare wire to bare wire, this removes one step in the process, creates tidy connections and is sized by the wire gauge, not by the insulation size.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever size is slightly larger than the wire. 1/8", I suppose.